# refer to single character of argument passed by user

Tags: c, string, arguments, hex, converters

I am trying to make a hex to string converter. I want the argument to be passed in at run. So far I have this..

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
        printf("%s = %c\n",argv[1], (int)atol(argv[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but in the `printf()` - `argv[i]` refers to all strings from that run. (ex "HexToString.exe", "ABCDEF0123456789") but what i am trying to do is refer to all characters in the second argument, so `argv[1][4] = 'E', but i dont think I can put a second bracket there because its a one dimensional array, It didn't work earlier when i tested it.

The output, and this may seem strange, I want to be the ascii equivalent of the hex value. example.. 'B' is 11 and ascii 11 is ♂.

So i guess what im really trying to do here is just that ^ but with a string of these values. I know this wont work as it is right now (it will read them in two characters at a time, convert and output) but for now though i just want to be able to convert single characters at a time.

also double brackets compiled correctly but error after execution.

Comment: You can put a second bracket there. `printf("%c", argv[1][4]);` is ok; `argv` is a pointer (to pointer to char), not an array; `argv[1]` is also a pointer (to char).

Comment: Also remember the proper includes; in this case it's `#include <stdio.h>` for `printf()` and `#include <stdlib.h>` for `atol()` and `#include <string.h>` for `strlen()`.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are interchangeable in many cases, because arrays decays to pointers and using array-indexing like `argv[i]` is basically just syntactic sugar for `*(argv + i)`. So there's no problem with using array-indexing with pointers.

Comment: Other than that, the [`atol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) function can only handle *decimal* numbers, and only of type `long` (which might still be 32-bits on some 64-bit systems). If you want to convert hexadecimal strings to numbers you have to use [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) (the double `ll` is for `long long`).

Comment: And I'm not quite sure what you're after, are you trying to print each character (as a character) by itself? Or as a hexadecimal number? Or a decimal (after conversion) number? Can you please edit your question to include the *expected* output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize a loop for all characters

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
 { int i; 

   printf("%s has \n",argv[1]);
   for (i=0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) 
   { 
      printf("%c = %d\n", argv[1][i],
      (argv [1][i] >= 'A')? (argv [1][i] - 'A' + 10 ) : (argv [1][i] - '0');
   } 
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! just fyi it needed the extra parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because `atol` expects a `char` pointer, try this

```
char buffer[2];

buffer[0] = argv[1][4];
buffer[1] = '\0';

printf("%s = %c\n", argv[1], (int)atol(buffer));
```